# How to install Erlang and RabbitMQ on OpenSUSE 11

Tags: linux, unix, opensuse, zypper, erlang

I'm still very new to OpenSUSE , and I'm trying to install erlang then rabbitmq with the package manager but it's not working , like when I do :

```
> zypper install erlang
Refreshing service 'susecloud'.
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...
'erlang' not found.
Resolving package dependencies...

Nothing to do.
```

Is there any simple procedure to install the two packages easily ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try http://software.opensuse.org . Select your openSUSE version there and try to find the packages. You can then download and install the package manually or install it with One-Click-Installation.